# Are value categories preserved inside a tuple (perfect forwarding through tuples)?

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding, stdtuple, std-invoke

I wrote the following snippet to test if I could perfectly forward values through a tuple and `std::invoke`. However the generated assembly looks kind of odd.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:29,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:29,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Cconcepts%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctuple%3E%0A%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E%0A%0A%0Aauto+foo(std::string+str,+std::string+str2+%3D+%22temp%22)%0A%7B%0A++++printf(%22Foo+executed+with+%25s+and+%25s!!%5Cn%22,+str.data(),+str2.data())%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+Cb,+typename...+Args%3E%0Aauto+async(Cb%26%26+fn,+Args%26%26...+args)%0A%7B%0A++++constexpr+std::size_t+cnt+%3D+sizeof...(Args)%3B%0A++++auto+tuple+%3D+std::make_tuple%3CArgs...%3E(std::forward%3CArgs%3E(args)...)%3B%0A%0A++++std::invoke(%5B%26%5D%3Cstd::size_t...+I%3E(std::index_sequence%3CI...%3E)%7B%0A++++++++foo(std::get%3CI%3E(tuple)...)%3B%0A++++%7D,+std::make_index_sequence%3Ccnt%3E%7B%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++async(%26foo,+std::string(%22mystring%22),+std::string(%22other%22))%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:57.59791122715404,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:30,endLineNumber:43,positionColumn:30,positionLineNumber:43,selectionStartColumn:8,selectionStartLineNumber:30,startColumn:8,startLineNumber:30),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:73.65470852017937,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:26.34529147982063,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:42.40208877284596,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <concepts>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>


auto foo(std::string str, std::string str2 = "temp")
{
    printf("Foo executed with %s and %s!\n", str.data(), str2.data());
}


template <typename Cb, typename... Args>
auto async(Cb&& fn, Args&&... args)
{
    constexpr std::size_t cnt = sizeof...(Args);
    auto tuple = std::make_tuple<Args...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    std::invoke([&]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>){
        foo(std::get<I>(tuple)...);
    }, std::make_index_sequence<cnt>{});
}


int main()
{
    async(&foo, std::string("mystring"), std::string("other"));
}
```

x86-46 gcc 12.2 -Wall -Os --std=c++20

Excerpt from line 30:

```
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&) [complete object constructor]
        lea     rsi, [rsp+16]
        lea     rdi, [rsp+176]
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&) [complete object constructor]
        lea     rsi, [rsp+144]
        lea     rdi, [rsp+112]
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) [complete object constructor]
        lea     rsi, [rsp+176]
        lea     rdi, [rsp+80]
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) [complete object constructor]
        lea     rsi, [rsp+112]
        lea     rdi, [rsp+80]
        call    foo(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)
```

As you can see there's a call to the copy constructor of `std::string`. Where does it originate from? My suspicion is the call to foo() using `std::get<I>(tuple)` which doesn't seem to perfectly forward the values. In this regard I'm lacking understanding: How is "rvalue-ness" routed through a `std::tuple`? Is the value category preserved inside the tuple or is everything converted to either copy or lvalue-reference? Is there a chance to optimize this as well?

**Clarification**:

My goal is essentially to achieve perfect forwarding from the callsite of `async()` to `foo()`. That means value categories should be preserved as-is and no unnecessary copies should be made in between.

E.g. When I call `async(&foo, std::string("string1"), std::string("string2"))` it should invoke the *move constructor* for the strings constructed in foo's parameter list.

E.g. When I call `async(&foo, str1, str2)` with predefined strings they should be picked up as rvlaue-references instead and foo's parameters should be *copy-constructed*.

Comment: I suspect you want `auto tuple = std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);` or just `auto tuple = std::forward_as_tuple(args...);` (I'm not 100% sure)

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's better, it gets rid of the rvalue_ref constructor! Still there's the copy constructor which I suppose is there because the foo() parameters are constructed by copy and not by rvalue ref... Can that be changed as well?

Comment: `Can that be changed as well?` Soooooo `foo(std::string& str, std::string& str2` ?

Comment: I must say I'm not following exactly what you expect. Instead of using a `std::string`, can't you use a [`foo`](https://godbolt.org/z/j5zzqWojT) that logs every instantiation/copy/move/destruction? It's a lot easier to see the effects that way.

Comment: @KamilCuk No the std::string parameters should be move-constructed rather than copy constructed.

Comment: Then `std::move(std::get<I>(tuple))` no?

Comment: @KamilCuk But that would move in any case, even if the intent was to copy construct. I think I must clarify the question

Comment: There is another problem with your code that might be very confusing if it manifests. Because you are using the name `asnyc` for your function and you call it with unqualified name and you pass it a `std` type, it is actually unspecified whether your program is well-formed. If the standard library function `std::async` of the same name is included directly or indirectly, then it will be found by ADL and be ambiguous with your template. Avoid using names already used int he standard library and avoid calling with unqualified name if you do not intent for ADL. (https://godbolt.org/z/zan7YorYT)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::make_tuple` makes a new tuple of *values* of the passed types. The result isn't a tuple storing references at all.

If you want a tuple of references you need `std::forward_as_tuple` instead. If you save the result in a variable, you are of course responsible to make sure that the referenced objects outlive the result tuple.

Also, neither `std::make_tuple` nor `std::forward_as_tuple` are supposed to be given template arguments explicitly. That will break their expected properties. (I guess for `std::make_tuple` it isn't that strict of a rule, but for `std::forward_as_tuple` it is.)

```
// tuple is a `std::tuple` of references of appropriate kind
// matching the value categories of `args`
auto tuple = std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

Furthermore, `std::get` will forward the value category only if you pass the tuple as rvalue. This means you need to use `std::move` explicitly. This prevents that an element referenced by the tuple can be moved without any explicit indication of that in the code:

```
std::invoke([&]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>){
    foo(std::get<I>(std::move(tuple))...);
}, std::make_index_sequence<cnt>{});
```

However, the standard library already has `std::apply` which does exactly this for you:

```
std::apply(fn, std::move(tuple));
```

Also, I assume that you need the tuple for something else as well, because otherwise you can simply do

```
std::invoke(fn, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

(And you probably want `std::forward<Cb>(fn)` instead of `fn` as well in case that is something more complex than a function pointer.)

---

Also note that using `async` as name for your function is not a good idea. There is a function template with the same name, template head and function parameter list in the `std` namespace. As a consequence, whenever your `async` is called with a type being from or depending on the namespace `std`, it will be ambiguous with `std::async` in overload resolution because it is found via ADL.

Therefore users would need to always make sure to call your `async` only by qualified name (which doesn't cause ADL). Otherwise the user's code may fail to compile randomly (because any standard library might or might not include `std::async` indirectly) and will certainly break any user that included `<future>`.

See https://godbolt.org/z/zan7YorYT for a demonstration.

Comment: Yess that solved it! The key was "std::get will forward the value category only if you pass the tuple as rvalue". This is due to reference collapsing right?

Comment: @glades Yes, if you look at the signature [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) it adds an lvalue reference to the return type in the lvalue overload. That way rvalue references in the tuple collapse to lvalue references when returned. That's intentional so that there can't be implicit moves from a tuple lvalue which might still be used later.

Comment: Now I get an internal compiler error: segmentation fault x) Looks like I found gcc's weak spot

Comment: @glades ICE is always a bug, so it seems so. But it is usually an indication that one is trying to something in an unusual way. Consider using one of the simpler approaches with `std::apply` or direct `std::invoke` if you can.

Comment: I've put it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75193528/stdforwarddecltypeargsargs-for-parameter-pack-in-lambda How would you do it?