# gcc compiler bug using std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)... for parameter pack in lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, decltype, perfect-forwarding, parameter-pack

In the following snippet I try to create an API for the `async` function which can be provided by a functor and an arbitrary amount of parameters that will be used to invoke a function call in asynchronous context (simplified away in this snipped). If the last parameter passed to `async` happens to be an allocator (as is one of the defaults for allocater-aware functions) it shall be hacked off and passed to the do_stuff() function seperately and not be pulled into the lambda capture. This is why I'm doing a constexpr comparison first (not sure if it can actually be done at compile time though).

So naturally I turn to variadic-capturing lambdas and stuff everything in there, but the problem with lambdas is that parameter types are automatically implied rather than named, which is a problem in this particular case because I want to move the captured fields out and into the function parameter list of the callable in question.

I tried `std::forward<decltype(bargs)>(bargs)` as you can see:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGISQCcpK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQSAOykAA6oCoRODB7evv5BaRmOAmER0SxxCVzJdpgOWUIETMQEOT5%2BgbaY9sUMjc0EpVGx8Um2TS1teZ0KE4PhwxWj1QCUtqhexMjsHOYAzOHI3lgA1CZ7bmwsJACeAPrEmAobW5jn2CYaAIL7h8eYZwuVC8DHqAjE70%2BPzMB1B/0BbgIXhS9Eh31%2BcK8p3ObmQs3wqDR0NhRyxAJxBBuKUwdwIxCYhAURKhXgyRhOYloqFERGItMBABETviQCAUiwEmLPDdrsQUgg8Mg7pzuUxeTiRSAYjcCG89h89lZ0cavrqWCi1Xq3JqMgAvGkEUgnSnU5hsImzYheBwnQQIWnNYB3VBUc5Gn7fM0W3UagjoUV2h0nSJOqMGXUIl2MViYAB0%2BfeJyOTAUChOABVMOb05hU1Ts2x87mTl9iMAmfqoZ7vQRfQR/RMgyGcSmK1Xo1bW%2B2m5D9ScQMK46KkSiad0q4wCCOnZqV6iLlOFDPO3OTIkrIkBWGoVC05bY/GQIn%2BaOs26AeWiazwsA%2BwPA8GVD8ucQpvjmf4Bm2gHbhW7zLvW14mlCTBeEQJzoKgdyzF4VBUBAmrAqCvQ4gAbqgeDoBAKyFlQDBOiqPIkPyDFqiQgpnOeZ4CtR6Kcd8JwCSctFUYhPyXjekbjjWFL1u%2BJxuDEdaujmTYtm2HYfN8KFoSWNyghACnmAAbMZQl0Wp7bGcZqmBgoPFieGgkcqhqDOsi9DsQRJAAO7NOgyoKLS7mYPhS4gPwxC%2BcQ6A4oe7wQLZKxNtRhpQk5aAMLMmCqCkxCLo%2Bz69sggieXg9ohk2ECHil4ZpYJeBUEWAhZTleWhQVOYBQ%2BoqPNcJE0sgJGPEBW4XH6kFDiNOLFQQAC0XBOlgRxZhAe6YClBrYPRtBcoxfKjdgKwcY5TmCZq4RkQA1iFJgAKxWGYJm3VeFw2mVDqqQAkvF50MFgqhYZgACOXiMNsOKfceh1nidp2nRhWFIrhEB3RYtGeWFEVRTFFyGfq1AMGsJyqTEtkY4%2BwCYKNbjffjmp9SFa0rNRz1UScLCoUwMQeTDdVw/zZntaKWN%2BTiS20CtpPqRtEBS%2B2SX5jVfMCxxAo7mFlPUzN80/WFDOrcFzNK/x/Ncerj4sEw113OE/2AyDYNWtrXCQpxl7G18TlcSc3RKMdytOb9V03fdVnPd1T7vbSX264%2BtvZfboOglakMFvq1F8Z7KsCQj2HI6j6Mgflws%2BaLuMxPFtFEyTZNF5qmsQ7Hor60zLMCmzHNNNz5KZ9ncPCV5kVl244uS4l8Vy3ZyWiX3qvm6KDcXM7TcgC3hvMzPpuXvPq9WzS8cA0oDvJ9Ngiuxe3GbwJXE3uJJrhL2lvhCJvGwxyO2qryzEf3tV8cgoelkAo1DqzB%2BJw8AZzfk5XKD88LmDMAACW6FyE4AB1EgtB0BnDMLddAYAwB3TcAweBToIF/zNicLgGhtq7VYsQD2XEOBrFoJwW6vA/AcC0KQVAnA3DWGsMKF42xsF7B4KQAgmgmFrAQJgJgWAEhUVIJdEAexEi5iMrdQIAAOAIGhbp6L2BoIykhbr6E4JIXgLAJAaGoRwrhPCOC8AUCAahEjOFMNIHAWASAMoRUtsncglA0DmjoPEZxsBgkpFCcQT68ZixGCkDY7hKRejOI4LNfEIFTCWGsGYDQJxZqoM5AU6k6BDCOGQB4iAkTomxJAMALgZgzDJNSZwDJcYsn8MsHkgpRSdolMwGUwQioqk1PoDE%2BMJFkApBSHcEiXAAh3BrLMZUxAWDGJaVkNJAB6EU2SHoWB6dsgAWkwE4Ujgj4F5BRPQBgjB1P2dYfQeAYjhKosw1h7DJHcN4QIPxhhhEADU8CYG8vEE4EBcCEDYvsLgR09jbK4Gw8RkjmZKJAGYAIuYNBcC4EZRIiQjJ4q4HsIyGgYRmI4BY0gViqG2O%2BQ4pxLiUXuLWF4qAMBEAgGynUFyZAKAJXUsoQw3QhAIFQN5DhYixlqiyMKiItAxUSrsbwMZowpkzLmQspZloVmqA2Wq4gAB5VCSrJXfJ5cgQ8nBeCWsaPgDhvB%2BCCBEGIdgUgZCCEUCodQ7jSC6GaXc4wXSbC0BeW8tYqAUlbM4LspcjzulcOeJsbYeh8ThHlaK8V5ruC8DpJgHYYjvL0hSJwHgHyODIpVT8jg2BVC8t5CcfVkh2YKCmSceZWLlm9gMiGp0ULG2wpWHm1FaxlF7D2LmCd06Z2zspdSqxt1J23S0YkSQkg9gBEkESrRWi9jSGrYy2wzK3FaDZZyiASBLV8sCYK9smbFXZqlaq1AIT0xypFY%2B5V3zDX1Mac0w1JrhBPotfWq16kbXBDA/a8IkHnXCFEOID18HvVqG%2BboBaQaUB9rDa8%2BAkbo3NTaZkvYAoE2HPyYU4ps1SnlJGesFN7rxgOofWa594jHiFt4MWpgpbc0VqrQyzgdaG1sVUFooys1jEnGAMgZAlCzC5jMBCvhOTLD9quTCmEcKR2sukbI%2BRlAK0Lv8EZXMkhGm3VumSpdWjcVGSMqQQ9kHnGuNHeiidU7Z3eYnZSvYXy/VHtPRclhHAzABfsZB4LaL%2BrEAyM4SQQA)

```
#include <memory_resource>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>

using allocator_t = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>;


template<std::size_t, typename>
struct nth_targ_of;

template<std::size_t N, template <typename...> class Template, typename... Args>
struct nth_targ_of<N, Template<Args...>> : std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Args...>> {};

template<std::size_t N, typename T>
using nth_targ_of_t = typename nth_targ_of<N, T>::type;


auto do_stuff(std::function<void()> fn, allocator_t allocator = {})
{
    fn();
}

template<typename Cb, typename... Args>
auto async(Cb&& fn, Args&&... args)
{
    auto tuple = std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    constexpr std::size_t cnt = sizeof...(Args);

    if constexpr (std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<nth_targ_of_t<cnt-1, decltype(tuple)>>, allocator_t>) {
        std::invoke([&]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>){
            do_stuff([fn = std::forward<Cb>(fn), ... bargs = std::get<I>(std::move(tuple))]() mutable {
                fn(std::forward<decltype(bargs)>(bargs)...);
            }, std::get<cnt-1>(std::move(tuple)));
        }, std::make_index_sequence<cnt-1>{});
    } else {
        std::invoke([&]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>){
            do_stuff([fn = std::forward<Cb>(fn), ... bargs = std::get<I>(std::move(tuple))]() mutable {
                fn(std::forward<decltype(bargs)>(bargs)...);
            }, std::get<cnt-1>(std::move(tuple)));
        }, std::make_index_sequence<cnt>{});
    }
}

int main()
{
    allocator_t allocator;
    async([](int i){
        printf("Hello World %d!\n", i);
    }, 10, allocator);
}
```

It compiles in clang and msvc, but not in gcc 12.2 as I get an "internal compiler error: Segmentation fault".

Apparently decltype() in gcc is not parameter-pack ready. Is there an elegant way I can still make this work?

Comment: You are using `nth_targ_of` when you meant `nth_targ_of_t`. Also the index of the last argument is `cnt-1`, not `cnt`. I am voting to close this as a typo, because I don't expect you chose either of these intentionally.

Comment: @user17732522 Wait. You're right, this is a type from retyping my original code to the snippet. After fixing it now compiles in msvc and clang but it still gives a compiler error in gcc (which is what I'm using). Any way to work around this?

Comment: As I already said in the other question the ICE from GCC is definitively a bug in GCC. Since I don't know exactly what part of your code is causing it, I can't tell you how to work around it and I don't have time to reduce your code to a minimal reproducer.

Comment: @user17732522 Idk either, but this works: https://godbolt.org/z/jobc91GEP. I basically just extracted the invoke()-call to another function. So it can't be `std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...`